# Spring-data-mongodb sum and count

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have a database with documents that have a category and a filesize. I want to query and produce a count of the different categories and the total filesize for each category. I'm using spring-data and I'm able to do exactly what I want using 2 aggregation queries.

My question is this...Is it possible to do this in a single query so that I have just 1 list that contains the category name, the number of times it is stored and the sum of the filesizes?

The answer was found

```
TypedAggregation<CatInfo> agg = newAggregation(CatInfo.class,
              group("category").count().as("count").sum("bytes").as("bytes"),
              project("count","bytes").and("category").previousOperation(),
              sort(Sort.Direction.ASC,"category"));

AggregationResults<FileCount> results = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, FileCount.class);
// FileCount class has category and count
List<FileCount> fclist = results.getMappedResults();
```

So no longer do I need this separate query to get the total file size

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I finally hit the right combination.  I added .sum("bytes").as("bytes") to the group line and then added "bytes" to the projection. The question has been updated with these changes.

Comment: You could add that as an answer.